# Best way to mock an RSS news feed endpoint in python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, rss

I am currently implementing a feature which pulls the data from an RSS feed, parses it, does some modifications to it and saves it to our db. I have to specify that this all happens in a Django project.

I pull the data from the RSS feed by using the [feedparser](https://feedparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. I've also decided to write some tests, to make sure that the news feed is parsed well and that the whole process (from pulling and parsing the data to modifying it to saving it in our db) goes well. In those tests I've even managed to generate a dummy RSS feed using [Django's feedgenerator util](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.feedgenerator).

However, I do not know how to effectively mock the RSS feed endpoint. I've tried using [requests-mock](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but to no avail. I know for a fact that feedparser uses urllib. Should I mock something from urllib to make it work? Or should I start a server in another process that accepts connections and responds to everything with the mock RSS data? (something made with `make_server` from [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.util.setup_testing_defaults)).

The end goal for me would be to have something like this:

```
request_mocker.get(RSS_NEWS_FEED_URL, data=dummy_rss_data, status_code=200)
```

So when feedparser calls that `RSS_NEWS_FEED_URL`, it gets the `dummy_rss_data`.